# What are alternatives to window.addEvent('domready',function() for window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, joomla, mootools

We are passing the url page to our Admin Emails through the 'refer' id in Joomla using ...

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() 
{ 
  document.getElementById('refer').value=window.location.href; 
});
```

This code works on some sites but not others. I have tried a jquery version with little luck, though I am open for suggestions. A site not returning the url via email is at http://www.freestylelitemeter.com while a site that is working is at http://www.comparediabetictestingsupplies.com. We are using 'refer' as a hidden field and everything matches, so I believe the issues is with the window.addEvent('domready', function() unless there is a conflict I am not aware of. Another interesting thing is the working domain has many more script files that has in the past found conflict between script files, while the smaller site has not.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At http://www.freestylelitemeter.com/, MooTools fails to load.  You get this error in your JavaScript console:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElement'
>   mootools.js, line 53 character 97

MooTools extends `window` with `addEvent()`.  Since MooTools hasn't loaded, `addEvent()` fails and your code is never executed.

You have a buggy version of MooTools, correct that and your problem should be resolved.

But, better yet, you are already using jQuery.  Just change your code to this:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#refer').val(location.href);
});
```

Are you even using MooTools much?  You may be able to switch to jQuery exclusively, and load one fewer library.

Comment: I would consider removing mootools, but I am finding it not working with your jQuery function as well. Could there be something else going on here? Also this is on a handful of sites and if I am not mistaken the CompareDiabeticTestingSupplies site has the same mootools.js.

Comment: Btw, I updated to the newest version of mootools with no luck.

Comment: @Shane - Move your script block below the jQuery script block.  Currently jQuery is loaded after your script runs.  As a rule, put all library script blocks first in your HTML, making sure dependent scripts appear after the script they depend on.

Comment: I got it to work on http://www.lifescandiabeticsupplies.com with your jquery code and moving the library. It was a little tricky adding because our script is tied to a module rather than template for when we update templates. I will now add to the other sites, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Shane - One more note. It seems you need an *older* version of MooTools.  jceutilities.js is trying to call `$E()` which hasn't been part of MooTools since before version 1.2. When your `domready` handler that calls jceutilities runs, it errors out, so none of the other `domready` handlers ever get called. You could check to see if there is a version of jceutilities that works with your version of MooTools. Or remove the jceutilities code if you don't need it.  By the way, your CompareDiabeticTestingSupplies site reports quite a lot of JavaScript errors. You should investigate those as well.

Comment: are you using firebug to find these issues or do you have something else. I have used firebug and just getting into debugging javascript.

Comment: That mootools error was because I just updated in hopes of fixing the issue, I have since rolled back to old mootools.

Comment: @Shane - The error you are getting now is due to jQuery and MooTools both trying to use `$`.  You can use MooTools and jQuery together, but it requires a bit of thoughtfulness and planning.  Using that ancient version of MooTools (~5 years old) might give you trouble trying to use MooTools and jQuery together.  You'll have to use `jQuery.noConflict()` and use a different variable for your jQuery calls.

Comment: thanks again, we are taking consideration of these issues with MooTools and will look into alternatives for future builds and updates along with noConflict(). Unfortunately it is modules that require some of this and modules we really are tied to.